# Help with active record relations

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord

```
class CreateActivities < ActiveRecord::Migration
  def self.up
    create_table :activities do |t|
      t.references :user
      t.references :media
      t.integer :artist_id

      t.string :type
      t.timestamps
    end
  end

  def self.down
    drop_table :activities
  end
end

class Fan < Activity
  belongs_to :user, :counter_cache => true
end

class Activity < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :user
  belongs_to :media
  belongs_to :artist, :class_name => 'User', :foreign_key => 'artist_id'
end

class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :activities
  has_many :fans
end
```

I tried changing my activity model too, without any success:

```
class Activity < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :activities, :class_name => 'User', :foreign_key => 'user_id'
  has_many :activities, :class_name => 'User', :foreign_key => 'artist_id'
end
```

**One thing to note. Activity is an STI. Fan inherits from Activity.**

In console, I do:

```
# Create a fan object. User is a fan of himself
fan = Fan.new
 => #<Fan id: nil, user_id: nil, media_id: nil, artist_id: nil, type: "Fan", comment: nil, created_at: nil, updated_at: nil> 

# Assign a user object
fan.user = User.first
 => #<User id: 1, genre_id: 1, country_id: 1, ....

# Assign an artist object
fan.artist_id = User.first.id
 => 1 

# Save the fan object
fan.save!
 => true 

Activity.last
 => #<Fan id: 13, user_id: 1, media_id: nil, artist_id: 1, type: "Fan", comment: nil, created_at: "2010-12-30 08:41:25", updated_at: "2010-12-30 08:41:25">

Activity.last.user
 => #<User id: 1, genre_id: 1, country_id: 1, .....
```

But...

```
Activity.last.artist
 => nil
```

Why is Activity.last.artist returning nil?

Comment: what SQL request is generate by your failed command line ?

Comment: Can you paste the SQL queries from development.log generated by those queries ?

Comment: development.log is empty. I think console commands are not reflected in the development.log

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok. It seems I had

```
attr_accessor :artist
```

in my Fan model. Removed it and now works accordingly

Comment: cool - you should probably close this then to save people reading through all the code only to find out you've solved it!

Answer (score 0):

What I notice is artist_id is always nil when I try to create the fan object using .create!, as such:

```
Fan.create!(:user => User.first, :artist => User.first.id)
 => #<Fan id: 43, user_id: 4, media_id: nil, artist_id: nil, type: "Fan", comment: nil, created_at: "2010-12-30 10:05:19", updated_at: "2010-12-30 10:05:19"> 

Fan.create!(:user => User.first, :artist_id => User.first.id)
 => #<Fan id: 44, user_id: 4, media_id: nil, artist_id: nil, type: "Fan", comment: nil, created_at: "2010-12-30 10:06:33", updated_at: "2010-12-30 10:06:33"> 

Fan.create!(:user => User.first, :artist => User.first)
 => #<Fan id: 45, user_id: 4, media_id: nil, artist_id: nil, type: "Fan", comment: nil, created_at: "2010-12-30 10:06:59", updated_at: "2010-12-30 10:06:59">
```

Why is this?